# OAuth consent screen for GMail API

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, gmail

I'm trying to implement OAuth2 authentication in a Windows Form C# application, with the purpose of sending emails through the user GMail Account.

On Google Cloud Platform console I'm setting up the OAuth consent screen and added "../auth/gmail.send", as my only need is to send an email.

Now on the application, when I start the authentication process, I'm asked to consent sharing full access to the gmail account, way more that I need. I haven't tryed to see if I have actual access to all of these features, but from the user prespective is just scary to consent with so many permissions.

Am I missing something in this process?

EDIT : The consent screen is waiting validation, is this relevant?

Answer (score 0):

This falls under the process of authentication where validation is required to grant permissions to specific or all features of Gmail.

Please go through below link in which , it is mentioned that you can opt for permissions and after which you will get tokens for further communication,

"Some requests require an authentication step where the user logs in with their Google account. After logging in, the user is asked whether they are willing to grant one or more permissions that your application is requesting. This process is called user consent.

If the user grants at least one permission, the Google Authorization Server sends your application an access token (or an authorization code that your application can use to obtain an access token) and a list of scopes of access granted by that token. If the user does not grant the permission, the server returns an error.

It is generally a best practice to request scopes incrementally, at the time access is required, rather than up front. For example, an app that wants to support saving an event to a calendar should not request Google Calendar access until the user presses the "Add to Calendar" button; see Incremental authorization."

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2